# How to select nested elements using HTML agility pack?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have a following kind of xml/html

```
<root>
<p1>
    <l1>
        <a>something</a>
        <a>something</a>
        <a>something</a>
        <a>something</a>
    </l1>
    <l1>
        <a>something</a>
        <a>something</a>
        <a>something</a>
        <a>something</a>
    </l1>
</p1>
</root>
```

I want to select collection of l1 tags and for each l1 tag i want to select all the 'a' tags for the current l1 tag. how do i do it??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HtmlAgilityPack uses [XPath selectors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx) to select nodes.

For your problem this would work:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"test.html");

var l1s = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//l1");
foreach (var item in l1s)
{
    var links = item.SelectNodes("a");
}
```

Note that I used an XPath selector that will grab **all** l1 elements in the document (by using leading `//`), to be more specific you could also do:

```
var l1s = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("root/p1/l1");
```

Comment: Everytime you exeute `item.SelectNodes("a")`, it will get all links in the page, and what you need to obtain are `<a>` tags inside `<l1s>`, so you must do: `item.SelectNodes("./a")` or `".//a"` if you don't want `<a>` tags to be inmediate children of `<l1s>` tags.

Comment: Did you actually bother to try this out before downvoting? The sample works as advertised - the foreach loop operates on each `l1` note separately, so you get 2 collections of `a` elements, first the 4 `a` elements in the first 'l1` then the 4 `a` elements in the second `l1`.